# Insert text at the beginning of every line between two patterns, inclusive

Tags: regex, perl, awk, sed

I'm trying to comment-out all of the _asm (and sometimes __asm) clocks in some C files.  So for example

```
_asm {
bla
bla
}
```

becomes

```
//## _asm {
//## bla
//## bla
//## }
```

and

```
__asm { bla bla }
```

becomes

```
//## __asm { bla bla }
```

Also, sometimes there are _asm lines without braces

```
_asm bla bla
```

And that should become

```
//## _asm bla bla
```

I doubt that this can be done with one single sed or awk expression, and that's okay.  I just need to be able to comment-out these blocks in the same exact way, so that I can undo everything simply by removing all of the "//## " patterns from the file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this as test file :

```
It works
elanblkaneglka
_asm {
bla
bla
}
bjkzrbgjkzbjkerzeg
zjegbzkjebzkjg{
   blabla
}
__asm { bla bla }
_asm bla bla
bajekbajkegbakeg
Next lines should not work
_asm
{blabla}
_asm {
bla{
  bla
}
bla
}
```

I tried this :

```
awk '/_+asm *\{/{bracket=1}/_+asm/{comment=1}comment{print "//##", $0}!comment;!bracket||/\}/{comment=0;bracket=0}' test.txt
```

**Of course this is ugly but regular expressions are not appropriate for this kind of problem.**

- Does not work if there are other brackets inside a __asm{} block.
- Does not work if { and __asm are not on the same line.

Result :

```
It works
elanblkaneglka
//## _asm {
//## bla
//## bla
//## }
bjkzrbgjkzbjkerzeg
zjegbzkjebzkjg{
   blabla
}
//## __asm { bla bla }
//## _asm bla bla
bajekbajkegbakeg
Next lines should not work
//## _asm
{blabla}
//## _asm {
//## bla{
//##   bla
//## }
bla
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  Unfortunatley, { and _asm are often not on the same line, but this will get me started.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^_\+asm/!b;s@^@//## @;/{/!b;/{.*}/b;:a;n;s@^@//## @;/}/!ba' file
```

Focus on lines that begin `_asm`. Insert the comment characters and if the line contains no braces or opening and closing braces, then we are done. Otherwise, print the current line and read in the next. Comment this line and repeat until a closing brace is found.